# Rails 3.0 .ics feed, works for apple products but not microsoft and android

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, outlook-2007, icalendar

I have a simple calendar feed that shows when employees are on vacation and I can subscribe to the calendar and see who is off.  This works fine with apple products (Mac OS X and iOS) but no beans with outlook or Android.  I think I might need to use one of the iCal ruby library's but would prefer not to if not needed.  Microsoft Outlook 2007 says the feed is not a valid calendar file when using the link:

```
www.nameofwebsite.com/time_off_feed/#ofbranch/time_off_feed.ics
```

for example:

```
www.nameofwebsite.com/time_off_feed/350/time_off_feed.ics
```

day_offs_controller.rb

```
def time_off_feed
  @users=User.where("current_branch=?", params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.ics
  end
end
```

days_off.ics.erb

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Website Name/Time-Off//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Website Name
CALSCALE:GERGORIAN
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<% user.day_offs.each do |day_off| %>
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:<%=day_off.id%>
SUMMARY:<%= day_off.user.name.titleize %> | <%= day_off.do_type %>
DTSTART:<%= day_off.start_date.strftime("%Y%m%d") %>
<% end_day=day_off.end_date + 1.day %>
DTEND:<%= end_day.strftime("%Y%m%d") %>
END:VEVENT
<%end%>
<% end %>
END:VCALENDAR
```

I don't think there is an issue with routes but here it is in case.

routes.rb

```
match '/time_off_feed/:id/time_off_feed', to: 'day_offs#time_off_feed', :as => 'time_off_feed_path'
```

I've looked at ri_cal and iCalendar gems but they seemed like a little much to generate a view but perhaps they are worth it.  Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Bonus points for simplifying the route :)

Thanks,

Jason

Update:  Added the following to the view to make it work, per the directions below.

```
DTSTAMP:<%=Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")%>
```

Works perfect on Outlook 2010, I'll double check tomorrow and make sure it works on Outlook 2007.

Update:  no go on outlook 2007.  Still searching for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook is right: your `VEVENT` component is missing the mandatory `DTSTAMP` property.

Comment: I should of said that it worked on outlook 2010.  Still not working on Outlook 2007